# My Cpu Temperature shows higher temperature than normal. Why?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, fan, temperature

I built a AMD Ryzen 5 2400g. for first year it works fine. then it starts to create problem. My CPU fan stops working. instead of installing new CPU fan i install my old DC fan. so every time i boot my system it shows CPU fan not running. its ok for me every time time to boot from bios. But there's problem started. During BIOS Login i noticed that, the temperature of the CPU was 75 deg-celcius. but i checked using 3rd part software and Ryzen Master it shows 40-50 deg-celcius. is there any problem in my motherboard, or due to aging factor this problem appears.

so i started to test my CPU with userbench mark. during load my CPU temperature shoots to 99 deg-celcius. Mostly my system crashed during this bench mark test. while rendering also my system continuously crashed. i dont know what to do. can any one suggest me a solution.

Details
CPU : AMD Ryzen 2400g
iGPU: vega 11
Mother Board : Asus B450-a
Ram : corsair 8GBx2

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously crashed"?

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious fix be to put the correct fan back?

Answer (score 3):

In the BIOS menu the CPU may not be using sleep states so will draw more power and get hotter. Once in the operating system the CPU will be properly managed and in a low power state when unused and so lower temperature.

If your CPU gets up to 99 degrees Celsius under load then your fan/cooler is ineffective and should be replaced, possibly along with the thermal compound.

If it is also crashing then that is another sign that you need to replace the fan. Running for extended periods at excessive temperatures can damage components.

You should get a good replacement fan. Not all fans run at the same speed or have the same amount of airflow, having an under-performing fan is the cause of all your problems and the only fix is to get one that is actually up to the task.